# how to upgrade puppet module in target-dir

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I've installed puppet modules as follows

`% puppet module install puppetlabs-apache --environment production --target-dir /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules`

How can I upgrade the puppetlabs-apache module?

`puppet module upgrade` tries to lookup the module within /etc/puppet directory

and puppet module [upgrade](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.4.latest/man/module.html) doesnt have a target-dir flag to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this myself for someone else who has the same confusion.

`#) sudo puppet config print modulepath

/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules`

`puppet module upgrade` command will search for module-to-be-upgraded in the above path.

Answer (score 1):

The `puppet module upgrade` command does not support this functionality, and there is a [bug filed upstream](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3087) about this.

However, since you can't always install into your module path you can just re-install the module using `--target-dir` like so:

```
puppet module install --target-dir /my/path --force name-module --version 1.0.1
```

YMMV when it comes to the dependencies if you use this method.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade command should follow the priority of the directory listed from the output of your 'puppet config print modulepath'

meaning it will search:
1) /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules
then
2) /etc/puppet/modules
then
3) /usr/share/puppet/modules

I hope this helps